# Ajax returns correct results but Wrong Format

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, for-loop

I am working on a tol using classic ASP, Ajax and JQuery and am at the final step am now start getting a weird issue.

I am submitting a query string via Ajax to my Asp page.  The asp page then looks at the values or certain parameters and then runs a for loop for each parameter.  Here is the code of one of my for loops:

```
if not edBlogRS.eof then
        for arrKey = 0 to ubound(edBlogDocsArr)
            if not edBlogRS.eof then
                doc_headline = edBlogRS("doc_headline")
                doc_headline = Replace ( Replace ( Replace ( Replace ( Replace (doc_headline, "–","-"), "”","''"), "‘", "'"), "“","''"), "’", "'")
                featuredRecords = featuredRecords & response.write("<li id="&chr(34)& edBlogRS("doc_id") &chr(34)&" value="&chr(34)& edBlogRS("doc_id") &chr(34)&"><div class=""sort""><img src=""http://img.deusm.com/deusm/sort_icon.gif"" border=""0"" /></div><div class=""delete"">Delete "& edBlogRS("section_type") &"</div><b>"& edBlogRS("doc_headline") &"</b><br />- "& edBlogRS("section_name") &" | "& edBlogRS("doc_published") &"</li>")
            end if
        next
        featuredRecords = featuredRecords & response.write("<input type=""hidden"" />")
    else
        featuredRecords = "<span class=""error"">** There was an error rebuilding the featured document list.<br /></span>"
        response.write(featuredRecords)
    end if
```

My two other loops do the same thing except have the RS and []Records values updated to match that specific group of content (ie: blogRS/blogRecords, rightRS/rightRecords)

My goal is to then have the results brought back to my primary page where each result will be added into the Html of a matching list.  Here is my Ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "docsearch_action.asp", 
                data: { pub: publication, docs: queryString, func_id: "2" },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(featuredRecords, blogRecords, rightRecords) {
                    $("#featured_docids").html(featuredRecords);
                    $("#blogs_docids").html(blogRecords);
                    $("#right_docids").html(rightRecords);
                },
                error: function(){
                alert("An error occured. Please try again.");
                }
        });
```

The desired result would be three lists each containing their coorespnding documents:

**Featured Documents**
Document One
Document Two

**Blogs**
Document Three
Docment Four

**Other**
Document Five
Document Six

However, the result that I am getting looks like this:

**Featured Documents**
Document One
Document Two
Document Three
Docment Four
Document Five
Document Six

**Blogs**
success

**Other**

I am pretty stumped after a while of messing with this and not sure what the issue could be at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

** EDIT **

Here is my new success call:

```
success: function(records) {
                    $("#featured_docids").html(records[0]);
                    $("#blogs_docids").html(records[1]);
                    $("#right_docids").html(records[2]);
                },
```

Answer (score 2):

You get your data in the data parameter.. the other two are the textStatus and XMLHttpRequest object.

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

So

```
success: function(featuredRecords, blogRecords, rightRecords) {
```

`featuredRecords === data` `blogRecords === textStatus`
`rightRecords === jqXHR`

Also if you were getting your data in an array you can just use the index to get the data

```
success: function(data) {
                $("#featured_docids").html(data[0] + data[1]);
                $("#blogs_docids").html(data [2] + data[3]);
                $("#right_docids").html(data [4] + data[5]);
            },
```

but you are getting all your data in one string so you will have to modify your ASP code to return the data how you want it then use the data object to put it where you want it.

Maybe create an array? or arrayList?  in the loop add each element then write it as that in your response

I actually don't understand how you're writing your code since I don't really know ASP/VB but I'll try to explain as best I can

Create an array

`yourarray = new array();`

Add what you need to your array - I'm guessing this is where you HTML is?

`yourarray[0] = doc1`

`yourarray[0] = doc2`

when you are done adding to your array..

`response.write(yourarray);`

Comment: Your explanation clears up why my results weren't being displayed how I wanted.  However, after creating an array and returning the results as you've shown, my first list is showing "<", second "l", and third "i".  Looking in Firebug, the full Html is being currectly returned but it isn't being parsed by JQuery the way I need it to.  Any idea?

Comment: I tried to expain as best I could in the edit. Hope it helps you get your expected results. @Yuschick

Comment: I don't believe the issue is with my ASP array as according to Firebug, the correct Html is being returned.  But in my Ajax when I am doing .html(records[1]); ect..., it is returning th1 first character in my returned Html versus the whole records[1] array item that I had built.

Comment: I updated my original post.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: no.. the response you are getting back from the server.  You should be able to see it under your network tab in developer tools.  Find what your response format it's coming back as.  A string array? Map?

Comment: I don't see a network tab under my Developer Tools.  But according to Firebug it is returning as text/html

Comment: It should be under `Net` in firebug.. then find your response

Comment: Another way I usually check response is go on the page.. then remove the last part of the url and add the ajax url.  So yours will be `docsearch_action.asp?pub=publication&docs= queryString&func_id=2` but fill in `publication` and `docs` with relevant data